# npm oracle db crashes silently without an error - node js

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

When i try to execute the app.js, it breaks and return silently without an error.
After analysing, the code breaks after the below line
" oracledbInst = new oracledbCLib.Oracledb(); "
at oracledb.js (in the path ../node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js)

The problem is working locally but not on server(OS: windows r12)
12
Configurations(64bit):
Node version:6.11.2
Oracle Instant client: 12.1.0.2.0
Visual C++ redistributable package: 2010

Is there any gap here ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved.
Here the OCI.dll file being referred from the the directory c:\windows\system32 and not from the path we gave for InstantClient. Even though the path has set in 
 environment variable it still polling in the above wrong directory. 
I have renamed the file OCI.dll to some other in the directory(c:\windows\system32) and everything worked fine.